# Using symbol "_" in subscript, mathmode

Tags: subscripts

Need to use a variable "`n_`" in mathmode, which returns error in case to be coded like `$n_{ _}$`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always show a [minimal but working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of only a code snippet and please always cite the exact error message you get. Without those information we need to speculate instead of being able to analyze the problem and show you a verified solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the symbol `_` you can use, e.g., `\_` or an `\underline` with a proper white space argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$n\_$ vs. $n\underline{\enskip}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, `$n_-$` is most simple and sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\mathunderscore` or `\text{$\mathunderscore$}`: they are equivalent if the symbol is only used in text style and not in subscripts/superscripts. Take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\usvarA}[1]{#1\mathunderscore}
\newcommand{\usvarB}[1]{#1\text{$\mathunderscore$}}

\begin{document}

$\usvarA{n}$ and $X_{\usvarA{n}}$

$\usvarB{n}$ and $X_{\usvarB{n}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]